# Why "netstat" doesn't show the ip of a server I'm connected to?

Tags: port, netstat, streaming

I have an *audio stream* from a Youtube video obtained by `youtube-dl -g <URL>` (this command outputs two links, for video and audio respectively). They have this form; `https://rr1---sn-uqx2-w50l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...` .
The ip of `rr1---sn-uqx2-w50l.googlevideo.com` is `181.64.63.12`

```
> ping rr1---sn-uqx2-w50l.googlevideo.com

Pinging rr1.sn-uqx2-w50l.googlevideo.com [181.64.63.12] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 181.64.63.12: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=123
Reply from 181.64.63.12: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=123
Reply from 181.64.63.12: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=123
Reply from 181.64.63.12: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=123
```

I run `netstat -an` when this link is playing on *vlc* and this ip doesnt show up, why is that? (I'm on windows 10)

```
> netstat -an

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:53             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1536           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1537           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1538           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1539           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1540           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1542           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2090           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9443           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10243          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:33060          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8631         127.0.0.1:8632         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8632         127.0.0.1:8631         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.254.121.209:139    0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    169.254.123.68:139     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    172.27.64.1:139        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    172.27.192.1:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.18:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1687      198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1733      198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1777      38.90.226.39:80        CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1813      172.217.146.201:443    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1822      172.64.148.218:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1824      192.16.49.85:80        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1825      108.158.107.120:80     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1826      2.20.144.232:80        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1828      142.250.78.97:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1830      217.160.86.51:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1832      217.160.86.59:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1833      142.250.78.74:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1838      217.160.86.61:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1839      217.160.86.59:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1841      217.160.86.61:443      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1843      217.160.86.82:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1844      157.240.197.15:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1845      192.16.49.85:80        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1846      157.240.197.35:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1848      217.160.86.51:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:53                [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:554               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1536              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1537              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1538              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1539              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1540              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1542              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:2090              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:2869              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:9443              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:10243             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:33060             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:53               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:80               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:443              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:1541             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:8000             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:9443             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53             *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53             *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
...
```

UPDATE:
In the image (I'm showing just the difference when running *netstat*), the left hand side is the *vlc* open without any connection, the right side with the connection. We can see in red the differences.
[image]

So there is only one connection established. Is that a CDN? there is always gonna be only one CDN connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many sites YouTube is neither a single server nor hosted from a single IP-address but instead leverages a large CDN solution.

VLC can and probably does connect to  a different IP-address then `youtube-dl`  to load that video stream. Using `netstat` without `-n`and rather than IP’s you should see host names which might identifying them easier